# how to use Alexa Skill as template for new project

Tags: eclipse, alexa-skills-kit

I have built the Alexa scorekeeper to the point where it runs successfully in the Test area of AWS.   I now want to create a new Alexa Skill using and modifying the code in the scorekeeper sample and if possible do this in Eclipse.  Help appreciated

Comment: Not very descriptive of whatever issues you may be having. As you noted, the the "backend" of a skill is a AWS process, which is just responding to a request for a response. You should be able to invoke your helper methods directly from Eclipse and debug and inspect their output.

Comment: Yes I am sorry for the poor question.  I am looking for some help on converting the scorekeeper skill to a different use, I have now achieved that by manually renaming files and references within the files but I am unsure whether Eclipse refactoring/renaming will do that for me in future.